# Rails 5 Navigational Menu from deep nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I need to create a dropdown sidebar navigational menu from my Rails 5 nested routes.  I have 4 models - locations, categories, subcategories and products.  We currently have 4 locations, so I created a query in my application_controller to default the path to our corporate location, San Diego.

From there, I created a category query based on the location query.  All is good, I can iterate and print the results to the view, with the category as the title of the dropdown.  I need to show the sub-categories in the category dropdown they belong to but I keep getting an undefined error.

*I know the nested routes that I have are not ideal for most situations, but this site needs absolute defined urls for search engine ranking...just so you know before you comment on them.*

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  before_action :load_vendors

  def load_vendors
    @location = Location.find_by_name('San Diego')
    @category = @location.categories
    @subcategory = @category.subcategories
  end
  ...
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :locations do
  resources :categories, path: '' do
    resources :subcategories, path: '' do
      resources :products, path: ''
    end
  end
end
```

**_sidebar.html.rb**

```
<div id="ss_menu">
  <% @category.each do |c| %>
      <div class="ss_button"><%= c.name %></div>
      <div class="ss_content">
        <ul>
          <% @subcategory.each do |s| %>
            <li>
              <a href="">
                <%= s.name %>
              </a>
            </li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you forgot to add erb extension `_sidebar.html.erb`.
Moreover, this is what the view should look like:

```
<div id="ss_menu">
  <% @categories.each do |category| %>
    <div class="ss_button"><%= category.name %></div>
    <div class="ss_content">
      <ul>
        <% category.subcategories.each do |subcategory| %>
          <li>
            <%= link_to subcategory.name, ... %>
          </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

What kind association type do you used for categories?

Comment: I updated the question with the .rb extension I accidentally omitted.  The associations are a simple has_many and belongs_to.  I'll try your code and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: @StudioRooster `*.erb` for views. Well, in that case, it should work.